# C# WPF Prism popup окно

Tags: c#, wpf

Как открыть окно в C# WPF Prism вначале работы без shell? нужно окно авторизации, и если все нормально shell

Comment: В чем проблема показать окно во время инициализации основного модуля приложения, который показываешь шелл?

Comment: У меня есть готовый код, но дома. Писать заново лень, могу вечером скинуть адаптированный